# How to read value from javascript function?

Tags: javascript

If I do this in javascript

```
var A = function() {
    alert(this.foo);
};
A["foo"] = "bar";
A();
```

I expect to alert `bar` but I get undefined, does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks

Comment: `var A = function() {
    alert(this.foo);
};
A.prototype.foo = "bar";
var x = new A();`

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` is the object upon which the method was called (unless you make use of the `new` operator or something like `call` or `bind`). Since you didn't call the function as a method then it is the default object (`window` in a browser) unless you are in strict mode.

The only reference you have to the function in scope is `A`, so you can only access it via `alert(A.foo)`.

If you had used a named function expression:

```
var A = function myFunction () {
```

then you would have had the variable `myFunction` locally scoped to that function which you could use instead of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the "parent" object of the function, not the function itself. There's no parent in the expression `A()`. To "make that work", you'd have to explicitly pass `A` as the `this` value:

```
A.call(A);
```

The way it's usually *meant* to work is this:

```
var A = {
    alert: function () {
        alert(this.foo);
    }
};

A.foo = 'bar';
A.alert();
```

The `A` from `A.alert()` is used as `this` value inside `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = function() {
            alert(this.foo);
        };
        A["foo"] = "bar";
        A.call(A);
```

or

```
var A = function() {

};

A.prototype.alert = function () {
     alert(this.foo);
}

var a = new A();
a["foo"] = "bar";
a.alert();
```